# Stat resets for Class change

Tags: ragnarok-online-2

I have read that when you change classes into a Monk or BeastMaster, you get a free **skill** reset.  Does this also come with a free **stat** reset?

Comment: Probably not. Stats aren't that important anyways; your gear will give you more stat points than you can ever hope to achieve with lvl-ups. I miss the old days of Ragnarok Online 1...

Answer (score 1):

Monk or Beastmaster only get their skills to be reset and not their stats.

Here are a few sources confirming this:

BeastMaster:

> http://ro2play.blogspot.com.au/2013/02/ragnarok-online-2-beast-master-skills.html
>   http://webjunkiesblog.blogspot.com.au/2013/03/best-beastmaster-skill-build-in.html

Monk:

> http://forums.playpark.net/index.php?/topic/200566-question-about-reset-skill/
>   http://forums.playpark.net/index.php?/topic/207588-is-there-a-skill-reset-if-i-choose-whether-priest-or-monk/
>   http://ro2play.blogspot.com.au/2013/04/monk-skill-build-tanker-and-damager.html

Comment: Confirmed as a Monk. Though be warned, **you will lose all your acolyte skills and _cannot_ re-learn them once changing to Monk** (this  probably goes the same for archer skills as Beastmaster).